# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} (xy)+ 4x^2 + y^2 = 0$ using the substitution $w=\frac yx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} (xy)+ 4x^2 + y^2 = 0$ using the substitution $w=\frac yx$

I have done most of this question but i'm unsure how to write the solution. This is what I have so far:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + 4(x/y) + \frac yx = 0$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac4w + w=0$$

As $w=\dfrac yx$, it follows that $y=xw$ so $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = w$.

so we now have:
$$w +\dfrac4w + w = 0$$

$$2w^2 + 4 = 0$$

Which gives the solution  $\pm\sqrt{2i}$

This is now the point where I get confused. 
Is this next part correct?

$$w = C_1 \cos(x\sqrt2) + C_2 \sin(x\sqrt2)$$
Therefore:
$$y =  x[ C_1\cos(x\sqrt2) + C_2\sin(x\sqrt2)]$$

Where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants. I have a feeling this isn't correct?

Comment: Please use mathjax to format your math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "As $w = y/x$, $y = xw$” Yes.  "So $dy/dx = w$.” No.

Comment: Regarding the above comment, the correct way to do it is to use the product rule from $y=x\cdot w$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1\cdot w+x\cdot \frac{dw}{dx}$$
Can you finish it now?

Comment: @projectilemotion thank you! I'll give it a go

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, I've got: xw dw/dx + 2w^2 + 4 = 0 but now I'm unsure what to do next

Comment: How might you solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(x)}{g(y)}?$$

Comment: @mathshelp101 That is indeed correct. Do you know how to solve separable differential equations?

Comment: @projectilemotion Yeh! I got  -1/4 log( w^2 + 2) = log(x) + c then I just need to rearrange for w, then substitute w=y/x back in to get it in terms of y and x. Is that right?

Comment: @mathshelp101 That's right. To be honest, you don't really need to rearrange for $w$, unless they ask for an explicit solution

Answer (score 2):

Your feeling that your solution *isn't correct* is indeed right. Everything is correct until the following line:

> As $w=\dfrac yx$, it follows that $y=xw$ so $\color{red}{\dfrac{dy}{dx} = w}$.

This answer will rectify this by discussing how to solve a specific type of ordinary differential equation where we in general can use the substitution $w=\dfrac{y}{x}$. You should then be able to apply this method for your specific ODE.

---

In **general**, a [homogeneous differential equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Substitutions.aspx) is one which can be written in the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \tag{1}$$
Your equation can clearly be written in the above form.
Using the proposed substitution, $w=\dfrac{y}{x}$, which is $y=x\cdot w$ as you correctly mentioned, it follows from the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) that:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1\cdot w+x\cdot \frac{dw}{dx}$$
Which is clearly **not** $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=w$, as pointed out by @MatthewLeingang.
Therefore, you can write $(1)$ as:
$$w+x\frac{dw}{dx}=F(w) \tag{2}$$
Which is a [separable ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx), which can be solved by rewriting $(2)$:
$$\frac{1}{F(w)-w}\cdot \frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\implies \int\frac{dw}{F(w)-w}=\int\frac{dx}{x}$$